# Populating select option using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I want to populate the options into the select box I am using ajax to fetch some records from database and in it's success function I am populating the fields my code was working fine but now I have change the function from where I am fetching the data and my results are gone means it is not displaying anymore but I want that functionality as well here's the code of my jQUery.

```
$('#cq-select-model').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {action: 'getPopulateField'},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var $year = $('#car-years');
            var $make = $('#car-makes');
            var $model = $('#car-models');
            $year.find('option').remove();
            $make.find('option').remove();
            $model.find('option').remove();
            $make.append('<option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>');
            for (var i in data.model) {
                $year.append('<option value=' + data[i].year + '>' + data[i].year + '</option>');
                $model.append('<option value=' + encodeURIComponent(data[i].model) + '>' + data[i].model + '</option>');
            }
            $('#cq-show-data').show();
            $('.show-data-desc').show();
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the code of my function which is fetching the records from the database.

I have this function before:

```
function getPopulateField() {
global $wpdb;
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ovdq_populate_fields");
wp_send_json($data);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_getPopulateField', 'getPopulateField');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getPopulateField', 'getPopulateField');
```

And changed my function to this:

```
function getPopulateField() {
global $wpdb;
$model = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT model FROM wp_ovdq_populate_fields ORDER BY model ASC");
$year = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM wp_ovdq_populate_fields");
$data = array_merge($model, $year);
wp_send_json($data);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_getPopulateField', 'getPopulateField');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getPopulateField', 'getPopulateField');
```

By using this function I am getting json response something like this.

```
 `200
:
{model: "Mondial Quattrovalvole"}
201
:
{model: "Mondial T"}
202
:
{model: "Mondial T Cabriolet"}
203
:
{model: "Portifino"}
204
:
{model: "Testarossa"}
205
:
{year: "1947"}
& More....
```

Comment: You said "my code was working fine but now I have change the function from where I am fetching the data and my results are gone". What did you have before and what did you change?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging 2 arrays of `year` and `model` is causing the problem.

In `JS`, when you are looping through `JSON`, at index 0 i.e. `data[0].year`, year is not available.

To fix this, you can change the array structure at `PHP` side as follows

```
$data = array('model' => $model, 'year' => $year);
```

In `JS`, loop `model` and `year` separately

```
for (var i in data.model) {
    $model.append('<option value=' + encodeURIComponent(data.model[i].model) + '>' + data.model[i].model + '</option>');
}

for (var i in data.year) {
    $year.append('<option value=' + data.year[i].year + '>' + data.year[i].year + '</option>');            
}
```

Comment: Sir this code is not working instead it is populating the fields and the results which are displaying is undefined

Comment: Sorry about that. Have modified my answer. Please check.

Comment: I have already resolved this issue the actual issue was I was not parsing the result in JSON due to which it was not displaying properly

Comment: You gave me the Idea but parsing it to JSON was completely found by me but still thank you for your precious time and effort it really means alot to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution posting it here so that it can help other in future. The actual issue was that the data was not parsing in JSON due to which results were not appending properly here is the updated code if any one wanted.

**Jquery:**

```
$('#cq-select-model').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {action: 'getPopulateField'},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            var object = $.parseJSON(data);

            var $year = $('#car-years');
            var $make = $('#car-makes');
            var $model = $('#car-models');
            $year.find('option').remove();
            $make.find('option').remove();
            $model.find('option').remove();
            $make.append('<option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>');
            for (var i in object.model) {
                $model.append('<option value=' + encodeURIComponent(object.model[i].model) + '>' + object.model[i].model + '</option>');
            }

            for (var j in object.year) {
                $year.append('<option value=' + object.year[j].year + '>' + object.year[j].year + '</option>');
            }
            $('#cq-show-data').show();
            $('.show-data-desc').show();
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP Script**

```
function getPopulateField() {
global $wpdb;
$model_array = array();
$year_array = array();
$model = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT model FROM wp_ovdq_populate_fields ORDER BY model ASC");
$year = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM wp_ovdq_populate_fields");

$data = array(
    'model' => $model,
    'year' => $year
);

$data_send = json_encode($data);
wp_send_json($data_send);
}
```

This solutions works flawlessly in my case.

Comment: Looks like you copy pasted my answer to create your own. No worries! Glad your issue is solved. Happy coding!